# Express.js not recognizing subdirectories

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm playing around with an angular/express/nodejs app. The server is quite simple:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public/'));

app.listen(3000);
```

My directory structure for the app is as follows:

```
    node_modules/
      .bin/
      express/
      mongoose/
      path/
    public/
      js/
       modules/
         myfirstModule/
            views/
            controllers/
            services/
      index.html
    package.json
```

And I'm having trouble retrieving anything deeper in the app beyond the /js folder. For example, if a child module is located in /js/modules/myfirstModule/... I cannot load it. However, if I just put it in /js, then I am fine. It looks like I am only looking one level deep.

Chrome console gives me:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I've set up apps for Angular + Spring(Java), but this is my first app using the new stack. I was wondering if anyone knew of a solution? I feel I need to modify the line:

```
app.use(express.static('public/'));
```

But haven't found the correct syntax. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to open [http://localhost:3000/js/modules/myfirstModule/views/something.html](http://localhost:3000/js/modules/myfirstModule/views/something.html) directly? I think you're doing it right, so I don't see the problem with express.

Comment: @RallionRI: Yep. It looks like the 'correct' approach is to list out the subdirectory structure: app.use(express.static('public/js/modules/'));
app.use(express.static('public/js/modules/views/'));
app.use(express.static('public/js/modules/controllers/'));
app.use(express.static('public/js/modules/services/')); I dislike this approach. I wish there was a quick way of simply telling it to map the structure for me. Hm.

Comment: That's weird, I don't need to do this to make it work. Have you tried to remove the trailing `/`? I don't see any exemple in the [doc](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) with trailing `/`.

Comment: As in simple ('public')? I can try.

Comment: @RallionRI: It worked. Strange.